# Accessing external central kafka message broker from Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, minikube

I am very new to Kafka and kubernetes world and trying to do a project on it. My requirement might sound foolish but its somewhat like this:

The Kafka producer and kafka consumers are only deployed in the local Minikube cluster. The Kafka broker is a central broker and not present in the minikube cluster. I searched google and got to know how I can connect Minikube and Kafka cluster. But I do not know how to send message from the producer(deployed in kubernetes) to this external Kafka cluster and how to consume it as the consumer is also in the Minikube. Could anybody please help me in this?

Edits:

Here is my corresponding K8s Config.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kafka-producer-deployment
  labels:
    app: kafka-producer
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka-producer
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka-producer
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: kafka-producer
          image: chamilaliyanage/keda-demo-kafka-producer
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8090
          env:
            - name: KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVER
              value: "localhost:9092"
            - name: KAFKA_ORDERS_TOPIC
              value: "FSMTest"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-producer-svc
  labels:
    app: kafka-producer
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 8090
      targetPort: 8090
      nodePort: 32000
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    app: kafka-producer
```

Comment: The location of the cluster doesn't matter as long as network connection works. Minikube doesn't "connect", your pods do. Please show your code and any specific errors you get when you _try to connect_

Comment: For reaching the external kafka broker, it's as simple as providing its address in your kafka pods. For the other way around, you need to make sure your pod are accessible. In this case probably via service of type NodePort.

Comment: The problem is I can not see the Kafka consumers attached to my formed topic in Kafka cluster. Also message is also not produced in it. I have the Kafka advertised.listener as localhost:9092 and added the same in my YAML. Updating the yaml for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a similar project, but where the Kafka cluster was running inside Kubernetes and the Producer and Consumer were on the outside.

As Kafka brokers can be contacted on a IP address I just used a [Python library](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python) to produce and consume data to a Kafka topic.

You would then just have to containerize your producer and consumer applications :)